# Android sockets: receiving data in real-time

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have another device & application transmitting data in real-time (every few ms) and on my receiving device, I want to:

1) read/receive this data, and
2) use it to update a UI element (a dynamic graph in this case)

The data sender uses a socket in a background service, using AsyncTasks every few ms to send data. To initialize, it does the following:

```
echoSocket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
```

And to periodically send data it does:

```
static class sendDataTask extends AsyncTask<Float, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Float... params) {
            try { 
                JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
                j.put("x", params[0]);
                j.put("y", params[1]);
                j.put("z", params[2]);
                String jString = j.toString();
                out.println(jString);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("sendDataTask", e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```

How should I go about receiving this data in my application? Should I also use a background service with AsyncTasks that try to read from the socket every few ms? How about communicating with the UI thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  The simplest would be to use blocking reads in the doInBackground method of an AsyncTask and call publishProgress() to forward the new data to the UI thread.

Then implement onProgressUpdate with code (running in the UI thread) that updates the screen.

You should be aware that your read may not receive the entire message that you sent -- you may need to read more data and append it to the input received so far until you have an entire JSON message.

By blocking reads, I mean something like this (in pseudo code):

```
open a socket connected to the sender
is = socket.getInputStream()
initialize buffer, offset, and length
while the socket is good
    bytesRead = is.read(buffer, offset, length)
    if(bytesRead <= 0)
        bail out you have an error
    offset += bytesRead;
    length -= bytesRead 
    if(you have a complete message)
        copy the message out of the buffer (or parse the message here into
          some other data structure)
        publishProgress(the message)
        reset buffer offset and length for the next message.
         (remember you may have received part of the following message)
    end-if
end-while
```

The copy-out-of-the-buffer is necessary because the onProgressUpdate does not happen immediately so you need to be sure the next message does not overwrite the current one before it gets handled.

Comment: Having some trouble conceptualizing this in code. `while the socket is good` - should this be in the `doInBackground` of the AsyncTask? So then it just keeps running and calls `publishProgress` to update the UI thread every few ms?

Comment: Yep.  It will go to sleep on the read waiting for the data to arrive and publish data only when something actually comes in.

Comment: This technique does not scale well if you are talking to many devices, but for a single connection it's the best/simplest approach.

Comment: Alright thanks, seems like a good starting point for me. For reference, how would one scale reading real-time sockets from multiple devices? Like 10 all dumping data as fast as they can...

Comment: Take a look at the Reactor design pattern.  In C++ it is used by ACE and Boost ASIO.  I am not familiar with a Java implementation of the pattern but I assume one exists because it is a common problem.   You might also take a look at DDS (Data Distribution System) which is designed for this type of problem (at a larger scale)